# I don't know how to send the value extracted from jsp to another page (in using for)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

I am studying while working on a project Personally. I've encountered a difficulty.
The difficulty is how to extract values from 'for' in jsp.

i want to when i clicked , that's 's values have to go nextpage.
But, as look at the code below,
If I use request.getAttribute, only the last value of the repeat statement is printed.

how can i send value to nextpage..?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMVkr.png)

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List` to store multiple account numbers associated with a user in `session`. I'm assuming your account numbers are stored as strings, change the `List<T>` type, if required.

```
<%
    // ...

    List<Account> accountList = DAO.getListAccount(userid);
    List<String> accountNums = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Account acc : accountList) {
        String accountNum = acc.getA_number();
%>
    <div class="row" ...>
        <div class="column" ...>
            <h2><%= acc.getA_pname() %></h2>
            <p><%= accountNum %></p>
            <p><%= acc.getA_value() %></p>
        <%
            accountNums.add(accountNum);
            System.out.println(accountNum);
        %>
        </div>
    </div>    
<%
    }
    session.setAttribute("anumbers", accountNums);
%>
```

Now you can retrieve all the account numbers in the next page from `session`.

```
<%
    List<String> accountNums = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("anumbers");
    System.out.println(accountNums);
%>
```